# Предпросмотр видео в YouTube мышкой по миниатюрам?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, youtube-api

Пишу скрипт для Tampermonkey чтобы просматривать видео, водя мышкой по миниатюрам: [YouTubePreview.js](https://github.com/sooqua/YouTube-Preview/blob/master/YouTubePreview.user.js)

Все работает на главной странице, в подписках и на странице поиска, но не работает на странице с видео. Звук воспроизводится и я могу мотать вперед-назад мышкой, но кажется, будто iFrame прозрачный. Я по прежнему вижу картинку-миниатюру, но если ее удалить, остается лишь белое пусто место (видео под ней нет).

В чем причина этого странного поведения? Может быть мой плеер конфликтует с плеером на странице с видео?

Answer (score 1):

Исправил сам: `playerTag.style.zIndex = '1';`